# JsPlumb get all connection from start element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsplumb

How to get the all the connection from first element.

With the help of JsPlumb.getAllConnection() it only returns the connection from second. 
Im trying to get all the connection and all the elements to fetch data from.

My code:

```
$.each(jsPlumb.getAllConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
            idx++;
            console.log("idx" + idx);
            for (var i = 0; i <= idx; i++) {
                var replyOnes = connection.target.childNodes;
                var varStoreHere = [];
                for (var x = 1; x < replyOnes.length; x++) {
                    varStoreHere.push({
                        question: replyOnes[x].innerText,
                        answer: connection.target.id
                    });
                };
            };

            connections.push({
                id: connection.source.offsetParent.offsetParent.id,
                pageTargetId: connection.targetId,
                says : [connection.target.firstChild.innerText],
                reply : varStoreHere
            });

        });
```

Return Value: Two elements but outputs only connection element at no two, first element is missed

```
{
    "connections": [
        {
            "id": "pro2",
            "pageTargetId": "state1",
            "says": [
                null
            ],
            "reply": [
                {
                    "question": "",
                    "answer": "state1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "numberOfElements": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move `idx++;` to bottom, when it's at the beginning of the function you are starting the for loop from the second id

```
$.each(jsPlumb.getAllConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= idx; i++) {
        var replyOnes = connection.target.childNodes;
        var varStoreHere = [];
        for (var x = 1; x < replyOnes.length; x++) {
            varStoreHere.push({
                question: replyOnes[x].innerText,
                answer: connection.target.id
            });
        };
    };

    connections.push({
        id: connection.source.offsetParent.offsetParent.id,
        pageTargetId: connection.targetId,
        says : [connection.target.firstChild.innerText],
        reply : varStoreHere
    });
    idx++;
    console.log("idx" + idx);
});
```